# Display the text after 3 icons in header of the site

Tags: html, css

we are displaying text "a" using `<p class="a123">a</p>` in top left of the site as here

but i want to move text "a" to top right next to 3 icons.

[image]

we are using following code

```
<div id="header">

<header id="header" class="page-header">

<div class="page-header-container">
           <!-- logo -->
        <a class="logo" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="large" />
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrcSmall() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="small" />
        </a>

           <!-- logo end-->

<!-- search bar image -->

<div id='hideshow'>
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/search_16.png');?>" alt="Search">        
</div>

<!-- search bar image -->

<?php // In order for the language switcher to display next to logo on smaller viewports, it will be moved here.
              // See app.js for details ?>
<div class="store-language-container"></div>

<div class="skip-links">

<div class="account-cart-wrapper">

<!-- account man image -->
<a href="<?php echo $this->helper('customer')->getAccountUrl(); ?>" data-target-element="#header-account" class="skip-link skip-account">
                    <span class="icon"></span>                   
</a>

<!-- account man image end -->

<!-- Cart icon start-->

<div class="header-minicart">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart_head'); ?>

</div>       
<!-- Cart icon end-->     
</div>


<?php 

// echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/switch')->setTemplate('page/switch/languages.phtml')->tohtml(); 

?>  

<p class="a123">a</p>

</div>
        <!-- Menu -->

        <div id="header-nav" class="skip-content">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
        </div>

        <!-- Menu end-->

        <!-- Search -->

        <div id="header-search" class="skip-content desktop-only">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
        </div>

        <!-- Search end -->

        <!-- Account -->

        <div id="header-account" class="skip-content">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
        </div>
        <!-- Account end-->     

</div>

    <!--<div id="header-search" class="desktop-only">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
        </div>-->
</header>

<?php 

// echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); 
?>
</div>
```

please help me to find solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: Position the text in the same way you positioned the 3 icons... Simple

Comment: @Midas Thanks for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.a123 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 999;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

I hope this will help you. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2vDd.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

[image: example of the code i added to your site]

```
.a123{
   position: absolute;
   top: 25px;
   right: 0;
}
```

Adding this to your css file will position this at the top right of the page then you can change the top attribute to position this next to the icons if desired.

Comment: if i increase the `top` value , "a" is hiding.

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe Strange, i have attached a screenshot of what your site looks like on my end when i add that css to the a123 class. Make sure you add px to the end of the value if it is above 0. e.g 25px.

Comment: i am sorry to inform for me it didt worked. may be i done something wrong. Thanks for support.